# SUM COLUMN B (Debit) when COLUMN A (Account Code) is the Same [Excel]

Tags: excel, excel-2010

Here's my table in Excel. What I want to do is. How do I sum the columns in (Debit) when the columns in Account code were the same?

```html
Account Code        Debit
 
 
412            3,291.71 
412            1,041.19 
766            263.20 
767            3,248.55 
761            2,000.00 
755            7,000.00
```

I want it to be like this where there's a same value in Column Account Code which is 412 and add their corresponding rows. Thank you!

```html
Account Code        Debit       Another Column
 
412            3,291.71        4,332.90       
412            1,041.19 
766            263.20 
767            3,248.55 
761            2,000.00 
755            7,000.00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the Consolidate method:

**Steps:**

1. Select the cell you want to insert total (In my scenario cell C1)
2. Go to **Data** - **Data Tools** - **Consolidate**
3. Select the whole range of data at **References**
4. Press **Add**
5. Press **OK**

**Results:**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

IF you dont car about repetitions. Assuming columns are A, B and C and data starts in row 2

```
=SUMIF($A$2:$A$7,A2,$B$2:B7)
```

paste in C2 and drag down

If you don't want sums to repeat

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A$2:$A2,A2)=1,SUMIF($A$2:$A$7,A2,$B$2:B7),"")
```

paste in C2 row and drag down

edit: seems that someone was faster than me :)

Answer (score 0):

Another Column = Sumifs(Range of debit, Range of Account Code, Account Value)

For example if data is from 1st to 3rd column and 1st to 10 rows then

first cell of another column ==SUMIFS($B$2:$B$10,$A$2:$A$10,A2)